# Compare Quantities in Nested for-each loops Xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to compare quantities in two different elements in the input xml and if the quantities match, assign "Y" to a varaible in xsl.

The output xml should have a copy of the input xml and an ExtnXSL element in the end with ExtnXSLCompleteShipment attribute with "Y" value if the **ReceiptLine** element Quantity and the **OrderLine** OrderedQuantity match for the same PrimeLineNo attribute. I was thinking that the xsl should have two for-each loops and a variable **completeShipment** with a Y or N value.

Here is the Input XML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Receipt DocumentType="0005" ReceivingNode="110">
<Shipment DocumentType="0005" EnterpriseCode="CostcoUSA" OrderNo="Y100000594" ReceivingNode="110"/>
<ReceiptLines>
<ReceiptLine PrimeLineNo="1" SubLineNo="" OrderNo="Y100000600" Quantity="40.00"/>
<ReceiptLine PrimeLineNo="2" SubLineNo="" OrderNo="Y100000600" Quantity="30.00"/>
</ReceiptLines>
<OrderDetails>
<Order OrderHeaderKey="201402041210274226042" OrderNo="Y100000594" EnterpriseCode="CostcoUSA" DocumentType="0005">
<OrderLines>
<OrderLine OrderedQuantity="40" PrimeLineNo="1" SubLineNo="1" >
<OrderLine OrderedQuantity="30" PrimeLineNo="2" SubLineNo="2" >
<ChainedFromOrderLine>
<Order>
<Extn ExtnSpecialHandlingFlagt="N" />
</Order>
</ChainedFromOrderLine>
</OrderLine>
</OrderLine>
</OrderLines>
</Order>
</OrderDetails>
</Receipt>
```

Here is the output xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Receipt DocumentType="0005" ReceivingNode="110">
<Shipment DocumentType="0005" EnterpriseCode="CostcoUSA" OrderNo="Y100000594" ReceivingNode="110"/>
<ReceiptLines>
<ReceiptLine PrimeLineNo="1" SubLineNo="" OrderNo="Y100000600" Quantity="40.00"/>
<ReceiptLine PrimeLineNo="2" SubLineNo="" OrderNo="Y100000600" Quantity="30.00"/>
</ReceiptLines>
<OrderDetails>
<Order OrderHeaderKey="201402041210274226042" OrderNo="Y100000594" EnterpriseCode="CostcoUSA" DocumentType="0005">
<OrderLines>
<OrderLine OrderedQuantity="40" PrimeLineNo="1" SubLineNo="1" >
<OrderLine OrderedQuantity="30" PrimeLineNo="2" SubLineNo="2" >
<ChainedFromOrderLine>
<Order>
<Extn ExtnSpecialHandlingFlagt="N" />
</Order>
</ChainedFromOrderLine>
</OrderLine>
</OrderLine>
</OrderLines>
</Order>
</OrderDetails>
    <ExtnXSL ExtnXSLSpecialHandlingFlag="N" ExtnXSLCompleteShipment="Y" />
    </Receipt>
```

Here is the xsd for ExtnXSL with which I need help with:

```
  <ExtnXSL>
                <xsl:variable name="completeShipment">          
                <xsl:for-each select="Receipt/ReceiptLines/ReceiptLine">
                <xsl:variable name="receiptQty" select="@Quantity"/>
                <xsl:varaible name="rPrimeLineNo" select="@PrimeLineNo"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="//Receipt/OrderDetails/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine[PrimeLineNo=rPrimeLineNo]">
                    <xsl:varaible name="orderedQty" select="@OrderedQuantity"/>

                    <xsl:if test="orderedQty != receiptQty">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'N'"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:if test="completeShipment != 'N'">
                        <xsl:variable name="completeShipment" select="'Y'"/>
                    </xsl:if>


            <xsl:attribute name="ExtnXSLSpecialHandlingFlag">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'N'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ExtnXSLCompleteShipment">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$completeShipment"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            </ExtnXSL>
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

> if the ReceiptLine element Quantity and the OrderLine OrderedQuantity
>   match for the same PrimeLineNo attribute

In your example, the PrimeLineNo attribute is empty for the ReceiptLine, and "1" for the OrderLine - so that's not going to match. Did you perhaps think of matching the quantities by OrderNo? That would be easy to do using a **key**. For example, applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="receipt" match="ReceiptLine" use="@OrderNo" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="Receipt/OrderDetails/Order">
            <Order>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@OrderNo"/>
                <OrderedQuantity>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(OrderLines/OrderLine/@OrderedQuantity)"/>
                </OrderedQuantity>
                <ReceivedQuantity>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('receipt', @OrderNo)/@Quantity)"/>
                </ReceivedQuantity>
            </Order>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to your example input would result in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <Order OrderNo="Y100000123">
      <OrderedQuantity>50</OrderedQuantity>
      <ReceivedQuantity>50</ReceivedQuantity>
   </Order>
</output>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mike! I'm sorry, the example xml was not potraying the requirement correctly. So updated it with two **ReceiptLines** and two **OrderLines**. Each Order may have multiple order lines, and so was planning to match it with PrimeLineNo. Also the attribute **ExtnCompleteShipment** should be Y only if the quantities match on corresponding Receipt and Order Lines.

Comment: @KrisG I believe you have enough there to finish this on your own, don't you think?

Comment: Thanks for your time, but my question is still unanswered. I am new to xsl and inspite of looking at examples, I'm stuck with looping in and assigining a variable, as the variable gets out of scope once it comes out of foreach. Your code gives this as the output xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <Order OrderNo="Y100000123">
      <OrderedQuantity>40</OrderedQuantity>
      <ReceivedQuantity>40</ReceivedQuantity>
   </Order>
</output>